# Router with custom browser history only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to change the route with custom browser history whenever user clicks on o button
but it hides the component whereas URL has changed

here is `App`

```
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" exact component={FirstLogin} />
        <Route path="/second-step" exact component={SecondLogin} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

here is custom browser history

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

and here is how i tried to call it

```
    onClick={() => {
        history.push("/second-step");
      }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I down graded `history` package to version `4.10.1` and it works fine, looks like there was a issue with v5